# Post request to login in Booking.com from Java

Tags: java, post, authentication

I need to login in Booking.com and i am trying to do it in Java. I made a post request in different ways but i can not get the html from de index page.

This is the target page: 
[Admin Booking](https://admin.booking.com/hotel/hoteladmin/login.html?lang=es)

I need the following parameters for login:

loginname=
password=
ses=
lang=en
login=Login

I know that these are the parameters because a partner made that login in python and it works.

The ***ses*** parameter is on the form login (as a hidden input field) and the loginname and password are provided by myself.

So... to get the ***ses*** i make a previous GET request and then i add it as a parameter in my POST request. I get without problems the html from the first request but not the second one (POST).

I know that the POST login resquest should send the html of the logged page because as i said above a partner of mine obtains that result in python. In addition, i also tried this with Postman Chrome Application ([Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop)) and it works fine (with the difference that i only provide loginname and password).

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;


public class Test {

    private static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    private static final String GET_URL = "https://admin.booking.com/hotel/hoteladmin/login.html";

    private static final String POST_URL = "https://admin.booking.com/hotel/hoteladmin/login.html";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String ses = sendGET();
        System.out.println("GET DONE");
        sendPOST(ses);
        System.out.println("POST DONE");
    }

    private static String sendGET() throws IOException {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(GET_URL);
        httpGet.addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        System.out.println("GET Response Status:: "
                + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));

        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        reader.close();

        // print result
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(response.toString());
        String ses = doc.select("#ses").val();
        System.out.println(response.toString());
        httpClient.close();
        return ses;
    }

    private static void sendPOST(String ses) throws IOException {

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(POST_URL);
        httpPost.addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("loginname", "467933"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "moncloa1895"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ses", ses));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lang", "en"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "Login"));

        HttpEntity postParams = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters);
        httpPost.setEntity(postParams);

        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        System.out.println("POST Response Status:: "
                + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));

        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        reader.close();

        // print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());
        httpClient.close();

    }
}
```

Anyone knows how can i solve it??

Thanks!

Comment: What do you get back from the GET and POST? And should the params be URL params or part of the HTTP body?

Comment: I get the html code of login page from the GET and nothing from the POST (just 302 status). The params should be part of the http body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow redirects. Add something like this:

```
httpPost.setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy());
```

Im not sure what the actual method is on HTTPPost, but HttpClient has this ability.

Comment: I've  changed  my code for this: `CloseableHttpClient httpClient =  HttpClientBuilder.create().setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build();
        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);` and it works!! Thank you so much!